# Shopify - get unique articles based off current article's tags

Tags: shopify, liquid

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user is on an individual blog article/post, I want to display unique "related articles" based off of matching tags.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{% for tag in article.tags %}

  {% assign counter = 0 %}
  {% for article in blog.articles %}
    {% if article.tags contains tag and counter < 2 %}
      {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
      <li class="well">
      {% if article.excerpt.size > 0 %}
          <div class="thumb-article">
              <a href="{{ article.url }}">
                  {{ article.excerpt }}
              </a>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
              <h3><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
              <p>{{ article.content | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncatewords: 40 }}</p>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Surprisingly, (to me since this is my first experience with Shopify and liquid) it works, just a little too well as it gets duplicate posts.

Is there some way I can keep it from getting duplicate articles?

Comment: Your link is password locked so we can't see it.

Comment: Does this code help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042090/shopify-liquid-get-related-blog-posts

Comment: Or this: https://apps.shopify.com/related-blog-posts

Comment: @NathanielFlick That seemed to work, I just have to hope they tag them correctly

Comment: Oh cool which link worked for you?

Comment: The stackoverflow link, the one I upvoted

Comment: Cheers. I'll make that comment the answer to this post, then.

Answer (score 2):

For those who also searching how to **implement related blog posts to a blog not product** like in the links provided, there is the fix for code above:

```
...
{% assign skip_articles = article.handle | split: '.....' %}
...
{% for ...
    {% if ...
      {% unless skip_articles contains related_article.handle %}
        ...
        {% assign temp = related_article.handle | split: '.....' %}
        {% assign skip_articles = skip_articles | concat: temp %}
        ...
```

*split by anything you wouldn't find in handle to create array*

ending up with something like this:

```
<div class='relatedArticles'>
  {% for tag in article.tags %}

  {% assign counter = 0 %}
  {% assign skip_articles = article.handle | split: '.....' %}
  {% for related_article in blog.articles %}
    {% if related_article.tags contains tag and counter < 6 %}
      {% unless skip_articles contains related_article.handle %}
        {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
        {% assign temp = related_article.handle | split: '.....' %}
        {% assign skip_articles = skip_articles | concat: temp %}
        <div class="well">
          <h3><a href="{{ related_article.url }}">{{ related_article.title }}</a></h3>
          {% if related_article.excerpt.size > 0 %}
            <p>{{ related_article.excerpt }}</p>
          {% else %}
            <p>{{ related_article.content | truncatewords: 40 }}</p>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread has what you need: [Shopify liquid get related blog posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042090/shopify-liquid-get-related-blog-posts)

It creates an empty related posts variable then defines it in a loop that looks through other posts of that same category. To repeat its answer:

```
    {% assign related_posts = "" %}
{% for article in blogs.blog.articles %}
  {% if article.tags contains product.handle %}
    {% capture post %}
      <li><a href="{{ article.url }}"><p>{{ article.title }}</p></a></li>
    {% endcapture %}
    {% assign related_posts = related_posts | append:post %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if related_posts.size > 0 %}
  <ul> {{ related_posts }} </ul>
{% else %}
  No related posts!
{% endif %}
```

Go to that link above to see the full response.